# How to write a shortcut loop in reactor fashion

Tags: project-reactor

I have a non-reactor fashion code like below, iterating over a list of checkers and shortcut return "BAD" if any checker return false:

```java
public static String oldWay() {
    List<Checker> checkers = new ArrayList<>();
    String param = "blahblah";
    for (Checker checker : checkers) {
      if (!checker.check(param)) {
        return "BAD";
      }
    }
    return "GOOD";
}

interface Checker {
  boolean check(String str);
  Mono<Boolean> reactorCheck(String str);
}
```

How can i convert code above to reactor fashion?

```java
public static Mono<String> newWay() {
  // TODO
  return Mono.just("GOOD");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn it on its head and use `Flux#all(Predicate)`, but the input Flux is one of all the `Checker` you want to test:

```
//simplified Checker version for this example
interface Checker extends Predicate<String> {}

@Test
public void allChecks() {
    //given the checks you want to apply, as a Flux<Checker>...
    Checker lengthy = s -> s.length() > 3;
    Checker startsWithA = s -> s.toUpperCase().startsWith("A");

    Flux<Checker> checks = Flux.just(lengthy, startsWithA);

    //...and given the param String you want to check...
    String param = "Boooooh";
    //... verify that _all_ checkers match the predicate that "param passes the checker"
    Mono<String> allChecks = checks.all(checker -> checker.test(param))
        //and map that result to GOOD or BAD
          .map(allMatch -> allMatch ? "GOOD" : "BAD");

    StepVerifier.create(allChecks)
                .expectNext("BAD")
                .verifyComplete();

    //variant when multiple params to test:
    Flux<String> params = Flux.just("Booooh", "Always", "Ace");
    Flux<String> multiParamChecks = params.flatMap(p -> checks
            .all(checker -> checker.test(p))
            .map(valid -> p + (valid ? " GOOD" : " BAD"))
    );

    StepVerifier.create(multiParamChecks)
                .expectNext("Booooh BAD")
                .expectNext("Always GOOD")
                .expectNext("Ace BAD")
                .verifyComplete();
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's brilliant! One more question, if the `check` is a blocking method, what should I do? Use `publishOn`/`subscribeOn` ? Or make `check` method return a `Mono<Boolean>` and like this: `Flux.just(check, check).flatMap(check -> check.test(param)).all(match -> match).map(allMatch -> allMatch ? "GOOD" : "BAD")` ?

Comment: ideally the check would be short enough and converted to a `Mono<Boolean>`, but if you can't, use `Mono.fromCallable(this::check).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())`